# python virtual environment activated but python command not available

Tags: python, python-venv

I have created a virtual environment on Ubuntu with

`python3 -m venv myenv`

Python version is 3.8.10.

Then I have activated the environment with

```
source myenv/bin/activate
(myenv) c@pc:~/myvenvs$
```

However, when I run `which python` I get nothing, and when I run `which python3`,  I get my system Python at `/usr/bin/python3`.

Something is off here, and I do not know how to fix it.

Comment: Very strange. What is the output of `ls myvenv/bin`? Can you run `./myvenv/bin/python`?

Comment: What do ``VIRTUAL_ENV`` and ``PATH`` contain? Does ``which deactivate`` work? Can you provide the content of ``myenv/bin/activate``?

Comment: ```ls myenv/bin``` yields ```activate      activate.fish  easy_install      pip   pip3.8  python3
activate.csh  Activate.ps1   easy_install-3.8  pip3  python```. So everything normal I believe.

Comment: ```VIRTUAL_ENV``` containes a wrong path ... Looks like that is the problem. I do not know how it happened though. ```which deactivate``` did not work.